# Docker contain receiving unsolicited HTTP POST Requests

Tags: django, http, docker, gunicorn

When i start my django app in a docker container. I get the following Error/Warning every 5 or 10 seconds. (the app is using gunicorn HTTP server)

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '10.255.255.12:8082'. You may need to add
>   u'10.255.255.12' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

My question is not how to fix the error, but what is making the requests? I realise that this may be as a result of some line of code in my app, and i haven't shared any of my code. I am asking if anyone is aware of anything with django/gunicorn/docker which would be sending requests, perhaps some sort of tool which makes requests periodically as a status test?

Answer (score 0):

Your input is vague, so I can only try:

- [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) from Docker image
- [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#healthcheck) from Docker run command
- [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck) from Docker compose (service healthcheck)
- healthcheck from used load balancer
- request from external monitoring